# How do I make add more than 1 modal box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have found out how to make Modal Boxes using html from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal2
I don't know how to make more than 1 work, I have tried copy and pasting but that makes only the first one work.

Comment: Are we talking about **stacked** modals or about **mutually exclusive** modals? The answer depends on what you want.

Comment: Separate ones, for example one has `Box1` the other has `Box2`

Answer (score 1):

You should add a second `modal` in your HTML page triggered by a second `button` element.

```
<!-- The First Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- The Second Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
```

---

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn2">Open Modal 2</button>
```

And also, in your JS code, duplicate your bindings:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];
```

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9tz0nh8/4/) I made for you.